# Позволить модераторам помечать ответ ответом, если автор вопроса так и не пометил ответ более чем за N времени

Tags: предложение

Есть много вопросов где есть нормальные ответы, но при этом автор забыл или поленился пометить их ответами, либо просто вообще получив ответ или даже не получив его перестал заходить на сайт.

Предлагаю рассмотреть вариант:
После прохождения некоторого времени, например 1,2,3 месяцев позволять модераторам, или сообществу на основании голосов помечать лучший ответ ответом, если таковой есть.

Это даст авторам ответов дополнительную мотивацию и понимание что про них не забыли, что повысит желание отвечать и активность авторов ответов.

Если сам вопрос не представляет ценности, мало заходов, нет ответов, то возможность вообще его удалять. Зачем лишний мусор в интернете. Хотя может такое уже есть а я не знаю.

Тут на мете много вопросов обсуждается, возможно и подобный вопрос был уже ранее.

Comment: Я когда-то модерировал форум, на котором было так принято. Могу точно сказать, что это плохая идея - будут отмечать зеленой галкой все подряд.

Comment: @PashaPash всего лишь раз?

Comment: @PashaPash один раз не считается ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ проклятый T9. Убрал "раз".

Comment: @PashaPash один раз не т9тираз :)

Comment: А вот меня бесит писать людям, чтобы они плюсовали/принимали ответы. Но приходится(не только под свои, под все непринятые). Новичкам вообще показывается плашка "примите ответ"?

Comment: @PashaPash Если один модератор решает, то конечно может быть и всё подряд. Так пусть решает сообщество или несколько модераторов совместно.
Если то решение было плохим это не означает что все решения плохие.
На стаке столько правил... Просто делать это осознанно а не чекать всё подряд. Во многих ситуациях реально есть ответ. Так почему бы ему не стать ответом официально.
А где сомнения так не чекайте.
Этот вопрос не о том что это может быть сделано плохо а о том что это может быть сделано хорошо. И из-за того что где-то кто-то плохо делал не означает что надо ставить крест на этом.

Comment: Кроме того можно эту отметку делать особой. Отмечено сообществом, что бы не было путаницы. Не понравится эксперимент, так можно будет всё отменить.
Кроме того СтакОверфлов позиционируется как база вопросов и ответов. Это нелогично что правильные ответы должны зависеть от лени или других личных факторов того кто писал вопрос.

Comment: Я вообщем-то не расстроился и не обиделся что мне поставили 4 минуса, но тем не менее напишу. Николас постоянно пишет что бы ребята высказывались на мете и делали свои предложения.  
Вот посмотрите теперь со стороны как это происходит.
Человек приходит со стороны, пишет то что реально видит свежим взглядом на сайте, предлагает идею. 
А потом оказывается что всё уже давно решили что дубликат и так далее...
Я просто описал как эта ситуация выглядит со стороны. Решения её я не знаю, но просто показываю про то что что-то предлагать стороннему человеку почти невозможно.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Модераторы - не эксперты во всех областях + их мало. Нереально разбирать несколько десятков вопросов в день, анализировать правильность того, в чем скорее всего не разбираешься, и ставить галку. Со стороны будет выглядеть как "на все подряд". сообщество и так решает - ответы по умолчанию сортируются по голосам, даже если зеленой галки нет. Механизм, который просто дорисовывает к первому чекбокс и дает дополнительно 15 репутации тому, кто уже набрал больше всех репутации на ответах в этом же вопросе почти ничего не поменяет.

Comment: @PashaPash Я бы не сказал. Для тех кто в теме СО тут всё понятно. Но для новичков неочевидно что ответ не помеченный галочкой является ответом.
Кроме того я писал выше, что это повысит желание отвечающих отвечать.
Человек обладает психологией. Различные проявления которые вызывают негатив у пользователя отталкивают людей от сайта. Те же минусы, или непринятый ответ, особенно, когда человек старался его писать долгое время.
Я понимаю что у модераторов на это нет времени, так почему бы не сделать механизм голосования как сейчас есть на закрытие и переоткрытие вопросов.

Comment: Ну вообщем я написал свою идею, и не буду париться, примут её или нет. Я вижу так, но большой проблемы не будет и без этого. А писал я как раз потому что чуть раньше тут был вопрос на эту тему.

Comment: @PashaPash по дубликатам ничего не сказано про «N времени». Кроме того, модераторы очень даже могут быть экспертами. А ещё в дубликате никто не ответил на мой комментарий, оставленный больше года назад. Голосую за повторное открытие

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, все же, "галка" означает, что **по мнению АВТОРА ВОПРОСА** этот ответ лучший (более всего помог автору), а не то, что по мнению большинства голосовавших (а почему вы уверены в их компетентности?) ответ хорош. Возможно, просто стоило бы в верхней части страницы писать подсказку про галки и цифры на ответах.

Comment: Возможно нужна "серая" галочка, означающая что система считает вопрос отвеченым. Конечно есть правило "система считает вопрос отвеченым если..." но проверить считает ли - достаточно сложно. По идее - если вопрос в списке "без ответа" - то считает.

Answer (score 3):

На мой взгляд будет ерунда, особенно, когда несколько практически одинаковых ответов.

Например, на C# любят писать ответ стиле циклов, а другим ответом в стиле LINQ.

В итоге: оба ответа правильные, имеют одинаковое кол-во голосов => нельзя однозначно решить какой ответ верный.

[юмор он]

Самое правильное решение - это ввести дружину коллекторов:

Сначала они обзванивают ТС'ов и просят мирно принять ответ.

Если это не помогло, то начинают угрожать.

Последняя капля - это вычисление по IP и выезд бригады с битами на дом, и выбивание принятия ответа от ТС`а. Вот это, наиболее честный способ.

[юмор офф]